# How do I identify an outdoor use ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I was recommended a "Panduit TX6 6000" as a weather-proof Category 6 ethernet cable. Upon reading the specifications for the Panduit [TX6000™ Enhanced Category 6 UTP Copper Cable](http://www.panduit.com/heiler/SpecificationSheets/D-COSP260--WW-ENG-TX6000UTPCopCable-W.pdf) I see no mention of the keywords:

- "outdoor"
- "uv light"
- "sun light"
- "water proof"

That said, how do I identify an outdoor use ethernet cable if I do come across one?

Comment: There is no standard specification or rating for outdoor-use ethernet cables.

Comment: Most outdoor Ethernet runs are either in conduits (so hardly "outdoor"), or direct-burial (designed to be buried directly in the ground without a conduit), in which case you want to search for "direct burial Ethernet cable".